# get data from another table if column is null

Tags: mysql

I have two table:-

tableA:-

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
  firstId INT(6),
  secondId INT(6),
  product VARCHAR(30) default NULL,
  primary key (firstId, secondId)
)
```

tableB:-

```
CREATE TABLE tableB (
  firstId INT(6),
  product VARCHAR(30) default NULL,
  primary key (firstId)
)

INSERT INTO `tableA` (
`firstId` ,
`secondId` ,
`product`
) VALUES ('1',  '10', 'hello'), ('1',  '11', NULL);

INSERT INTO `tableB` (`firstId`, `product`) VALUES ('1', 'original');
```

Now i will have `firstId` and `secondId`, and i have to fetch product details `but condition is` if combination ( firstId and secondId) lies in 
tableA then get product details from it and if it is NULL then get product details from TableB in respect to `firstId`.

For Eg:-

If i have `firstID` = 1 and `secondId` = 10 then `hello` shold get as output

If i have `firstID` = 1 and `secondId` = 11 then `original` shold get as output

If i have `firstID` = 1 and `secondId` = 12 then `original` shold get as output

I need this in one query if possible. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It *may* be possible to do this in a single query with enough conditionals, but I'm not going to try. I'd suggest that the correct solution here is an entirely different schema. Some points to consider: 

- `firstID` and `secondID` are not very descriptive names (same goes for `tableA` & `tableB`)
- it sounds like `tableB` is really the primary table, and `tableA` lists sub-products; your queries would be easier if your schema better reflected the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a control flow function inside a mysql statement:

```
$first='1';$second='10';


SELECT IF( exists(select * FROM tableA WHERE  
tableA.firstId =  '$first' and tableA.secondId =  '$second'
and tableA.product!= 'NULL'),tableA.product, tableB.product )
FROM tableA, tableB ;
```

Comment: Its not working. it always give two output. for `(1,10)` it gives `hello,original`  which should be `hello`, for `(1,11)` it gives `original,original` which should come `original`. check in question i have given example

Comment: The SELECT statament answer for each file in tableA, for (1,10) gives hello, original.